# Weighted vs Non weighted scores for unbalanced classes

Tags: machine-learning, unbalanced-classes, scoring-rules

I have a dataset which has 99.8% negatives and 0.2% positives. The scores I have got for my model(built using XGBoost) is as follows:

```
Testing dataset
F1 score=0.1276595744680851
Precision=0.07086614173228346
Recall=0.6428571428571429
Weighted F1 =0.8821858216331502
Weighted Precision=0.9717719236678019
Weighted Recall=0.8176426982950333
ROC AUC=0.7321023034497675

Samples:1321 Negative,28 Negative
```

I am not sure which metric to focus and optimize for this case. Should I aim for the normal F1 score or the weighted one?

I understand my model is overfitting.